# UITableview stops responding when using translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I want to add a view with a tableview in it in code.
I define the view in storyboard like in the image.
[image: timechooser in storyboard]

In my view controller I set the place and size using the following code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // bunch of non-related code

    timeTableView.delegate = self
    timeTableView.dataSource = self

    timeTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    timeTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 32

    timeChooser.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
}



@IBAction func onTimeLabelPressed(_ sender: AnyObject){
    view.addSubview(timeChooser)
    let topConstraint = timeChooser.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewdayTime.bottomAnchor)
    let leftConstraint = timeChooser.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewdayTime.leftAnchor)
    //let heightConstraint = timeChooser.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 128)
    //let widthConstraint = timeChooser.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: viewdayTime.widthAnchor)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([topConstraint,leftConstraint, /*heightConstraint, widthconstraint*/])
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
    timeChooser.alpha=0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2){
        self.timeChooser.alpha=1.0}
}
```

The function onTimeLabelPressed makes the view appear under and left aligned with a label.

Problem is the tableview will not scroll or respond otherwise as long as the line

> timeChooser.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false

is present. Removing it breaks the positioning constraints but the tableview behaves normally.

Anybody any ideas? Did not find any question describing my witnessed behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your `timeChooser` constraints to establish its `width` and `height`.  It would probably be best to set `right` and `bottom` constraints.

```
let rightConstraint = timeChooser.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor)
let bottomConstraint = timeChooser.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
```

Comment: I did use heigth and width constraints, commented out in the code sample, but those made no difference. I'll try your sugggestion though.

Comment: You'll be better off with right and bottom constraints letting the size of the screen establish the width and height. Your constraints have less thans and greater thans in them which gives the system freedom to choose something that doesn't work for you, such as 0.

Comment: right and bottom constraints work where as height and width did not. Strange, must be something in the way auto layout works with tableviews

Comment: I have to amend this: height and width constraints are allright to use, but I forgot to set the constraints of the UITableview with respect to its superview timeChooser. This resulted in responsive area to be smaller than the shown text.